# Instalação do Android Studio: caminho para o JDK

Tags: android, android-studio

a algumas semanas instalei o Android Studio e estava desenvolvendo o projeto e "acidentalmente" apaguei umas pastas que não devia (descuido da minha parte).

Não encontrei solução para reparar as pastas apagadas então resolvi desinstalar o AS e instalar de novo.

Só que agora estou encontrando um problema que está me tirando do sério a 2 dias.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já procurei todo tipo de ajuda e sempre explicam que o problema é no `JAVA_PATH`, `HOME_PATH`, `PATH`, `CLASS_PATH`, e tantos outros, mas **Nenhuma** dessas variáveis de sistema solucionaram meu problema.

Já removi e reinstalei o JDK  `jdk-7u80-windows-x64` umas trilhões de vezes e o instalador parece não encontrar o caminho do bendito.

Claro! Existe um campo pra eu referenciar diretamente para ele, mas o erro continua surgindo.

Grato pela compreensão.

**TL;DR**

O erro é esse, as variáveis do sistema estão setadas e não consigo de jeito nenhum continuar a instalação do Android Studio.

**EDITADO 28/05**

Acabou que consegui instalar hoje pela manhã.

Fui no painel de controle e mandei desinstalar o JDK. Não sei o que eu fiz, já que no dia que fiz a pergunta tentei fazer isso umas 4 vezes e não resolvia o problema.

Obrigado a todos.

Comment: Está instalando qual versão do android studio? Pois tem a versão 32 bits(x86) e a de 64(x86_64).

Comment: Qual valor de `JAVA_HOME`? Qual seu `PATH` completo (não precisa tudo, obviamente, remova as partes nada a ver com java)?

Comment: A versão do AS que estou instalando é x64

O valor do JAVA_HOME > "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80"

Comment: Tive esse problema essa semana, eu instalei no disco D e a versão 64 bits, só que ele foi parar em C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55 verifica se o seu esta ai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Baixe a IDE Android Studio mais atual, e baixe seu JDK conforme a sua máquina 32bits ou 64bits, para que sua instalação dê certo, como saber se sua máquina é 32bits ou 64bits?

> Tecle `windows + r` e digite `control` e tecle enter, agora vá em
>   Sistema e lá você saberá e terá a informação.

Outra coisa importante:

- Em Sistema
- Configurações Avançadas do Sistema
- Propriedades do Sistema
- Avançado
- Variáveis de Ambiente

> Se você tem `- Variáveis de usuário -` iguais as `- Variáveis do sistema -` sua instalação sempre dará erro, exclua as `- Variáveis de usuário -` erradas e inclua só aquelas do tutorial em `- Variáveis do sistema -`, como visto abaixo.

### -- Modo Errado --

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

### -- Modo Correto --

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Cuidado também com duplicatas de JDK em, `Valor da variável`, exemplo:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin;C:\Program Files\Algum
>   Software;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_41\bin;

Mantenha só o JDK mais atual, não duplique as entradas no `Valor da variável`, assim:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin;C:\Program Files\Algum Software;

Quer dizer o valor de seu JDK, só aparece uma vez em cada variável!

Comment: Opa, obrigado Paulo. Espero que mais alguém se beneficie da sua resposta