# Erro ao selecionar emulador no Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Boa tarde. 
Estou começando a estudar Android e a utilizar o Android Studio. Cliquei para executar a aplicação e apareceu a janela solicitando um novo emulador.

Já fiz isso antes em outro computador e funcionava normalmente após as configurações, como na imagem a seguir.

[image: Segunda]

Porém agora, quando clico em Finish, fica carregando:

[image: Terceira]

E depois de um tempo volta à tela inicial, solicitando novamente um emulador. Estou fazendo algo errado, ou alguma configuração está incorreta?

Comment: precisa verificar suas configurações do java e do Android SDK

Comment: Vi que você está utilizando a API 6.0 no emulador, seu projeto está configurado para funcionar com esta API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode iniciar sua vm de duas maneiras, a primeira é através do modo padrão rodando sua aplicação comando **Shift+F10** e a outra forma é através do AVD Manager.

**Resolução do Problema:**

Já passei por esse problema, possível *delay* na sincronização do **ADB**:

Depois de criar sua vm, se não aparecer nenhuma máquina virtual, não se preocupe, feche essa janela, depois volte a rodar sua aplicação **Shift+F10** e ai aguarde um pouco ate o Android listar suas vms, depois escolha a maquina que deseja iniciar e inicie clicando ok.

> **Obs:** Em `Select Deployment Target` desmarque a opção `[]Use same selection for future launches`, visto que se essa
>   opção estiver marcada e se você criou uma vm com algum erro,
>   sempre que rodar sua aplicação você terá um erro e nunca iniciará nada.

---

**Recomendação para criação de sua VM:**

Percebi que você está usando uma Resolução muito alta *1080x1920* baixe para *480x800* ou *320x480* e percebi também que você está usando a **API 23 (6.0)** tente baixar sua API para **API 21 (5.0)** ou **API 19 (4.4)**.

---

**Criando uma VM Básica:**

Mo menu toolbar clique em AVD Manager e em seguida...

clique em [+ Create Virtual Device...]

*Janela* - **Select Hardware**

```
Category    Name              Size    Resolution    Density 
Phone       3.2"QVGA(ADP2)    3,2"    320x480       mdpi
```

clique em [Next]

*Janela* - **System image**

escolha a tab [Other images]

```
Release Name    API Level    ABI            Target
Kit Kat         19           armeabi-v7a    Android 4.4(With Google APIs)
```

> **Obs:** Se não possuir a imagem acima faça o Download(Instale e clique em [Finish]) ou selecione outra img, fica a seu critério...

Depois clique em [Next]

*Janela* - **Android Virtual Device - Verify Configuration**

```
(!) AVD Name 3.2" QVGA (ADP2) API 19 <- mude para -> 3.2 QVGA (ADP2) API 19

Emulated        Graphics:     Software GLES 2.0
Performance
```

- Agora clique em [Finish]
- Aguarde enquanto sua maquina virtual é criada...
- Depois selecione a sua nova VM e inicie para testar...

> **Aviso Importante:** Se você criou essa nova **VM**, com as configurações acima, saiba que é necessário adicionar em seu arquivo `build.gradle`
>   a API 19 (4.4) ao seu `minSdkVersion`, dessa maneira:

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "package de seu app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

---

Alguns links que podem ajudar em relação as variáveis de ambiente:

- [Android Studio não encontra JDK durante instalação.Como resolver?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/96317)
- [Instalação do Android Studio: caminho para o JDK](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/130809)

Veja também: 
[Como aumentar a memória da IDE Android Studio?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131525/como-aumentar-a-mem%C3%B3ria-da-ide-android-studio)

---

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

Talvez o projeto que você está tentando rodar não seja compatível com a versão da **API** configurada na **AVD**. Tenta verificar no seu `build.gradle` se o **targetSDK** e o **minimumSdk** é menor ou igual a versão do seu emulador.

Desmarque também a opção **Tools > Android > Enable ADB Integration**.

Talvez isto também te ajude: [Android studio: emulator is running but not showing up in Run App “choose a running device”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29198528/5263999).